# runlevel + how to force multi user mode from run-level 3

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, runlevel

we know that `runlevl` of multi user mode is

```
N 5
```

but on our redhat 7.2 we get the following

```
runlevel

5 3
```

what is the meaning of this run-level ?

how to change this machine to multi user mode ( full permissions )

and when we do

```
who -r
```

we get

```
run-level 3                last=5
```

Note - we perform `reboot/init 6` , but still we are in `run-level 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run level 3 is multiuser, 5 is graphical. RHEL 7 uses systemd instead of system v, and the runlevel is replaced by systemd targets. it can be changed with sytsemctl:

```
systemctl isolate graphical.target
```

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-change-runlevels-in-rhel7-with-systemd/